# Selecting a link nestled inside a h2 element which is inside a div using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, iteration

I have the following HTML:

```
     <div class="company-name">

            <div class="search-result">
              <h2 class="search-result-title">
                <a href="/test1">Testing 1/a>
              </h2>
              <p class="search-pst">
                Test1
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="search-result">
              <h2 class="search-result-title">
                <a href="/test2">Testing 2/a>
              </h2>
              <p class="search-pst">
                Test2
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="search-result">
              <h2 class="search-result-title">
                <a href="/test3">Testing 3/a>
              </h2>
              <p class="search-pst">
              Test3
              </p>
            </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to iterate through each div within the 'company-name' div and selecting each link.

So far i have:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("company-name"));
         for (WebElement element : elements) {


             }
```

Which gets the entire company-name div. I'm a little stuck on how i would access each link within the nested divs.

Comment: Did you try `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".search-result a"))`?

Comment: Thanks, i have managed now to select the first link in the list of elements but it doesn't select any others.

Comment: Share the code which you tried to *select* the links